# Keeping dry inside car door

Tags: car

I deliver newspapers. (Yes, some people still do read them.) Anyhow, the driver's side window is almost always open and I'm subject to getting soaking wet when it rains.  Any and all ideas would be appreciated and seriously considered.

Comment: Hi Robert, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing your knowledge and experience. Do you have to toss the paper or do you put it into a curb side newspaper delivery box?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a hack, per se; but, there's a flip window attachment made for rural postal carriers that attaches to your car window without special attachments.

[image: Car flip window]

It's marketed and sold as a "Flip Window" by a company in the United States by the name of Postal Things, Inc.

You could make a similar kind of "awning" for your window that attaches by plasticized magnetic strips along the top of the window at the roofline. You would reach out from under the flap to deliver the paper.

Good Luck.

Comment: Good product. I worry about the hard plastic lower edge causing skin abrasion. Perhaps find a way to soften this edge, for example you could cut a length of clear plastic tubing and make a single cut along its edge and then silastic this to the edge.

Answer (score 0):

You could tape a moderately-heavy (5 or 10 mil) piece of vinyl or polyethylene sheet over the window opening and cut straight lines across the center, vertically, horizontally and diagonally in a "starburst". If the sheet is stiff enough, you could drive at moderate sped and little water would get through, but you should be able to push your hand through easily.

[image: Plastic Port]

*N.B.* Don't leave sharp points in the center, lest it cut your arm or cause it to get stuck pulling back! A little hole in the center should be acceptable.